# What are the cohomology groups $H^d(BSO_\infty,Z)$ and $H^d(BO_\infty,Z)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology

The Theorem 1.5 and 1.6 of

Brown, Edgar H., Jr. The cohomology of BSOn and BOn with integer coefficients. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 85 (1982), no. 2, 283–288.

give a general answer for $H^d(BSO_n,Z)$ and  $H^d(BO_n,Z)$, which are very complicated. I wonder what are $H^d(BSO_\infty,Z)$ and  $H^d(BO_\infty,Z)$ for $d=1,2,3,4,5$?

Comment: The inclusions $BO(n)\to BO$ and $BSO(n)\to BSO$ are $n$-connected. So the $d$-dimensional cohomology in the infinite case is the same as for $n$ very large compared to $d$. There's no getting round the fact that these groups are complicated! But I suppose the description of the cohomology *ring* is simpler in the infinite case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Theorem 1.5 and 1.6 you quote give the answer.

More precisely, for $SO$, in the range $d<6$, the only polynomial generators
are $p_1$ which has degree 4, $\delta(w_2)$ with degree 3 and $\delta(w_4)$ with degree 5. The only  relations are $2\delta(w_{2i})=0$, which gives $$H^d(BSO_{\infty};\mathbb{Z})\cong 0,\quad (d=1,2),$$
$$H^d(BSO_{\infty};\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}/2 ,\quad (d=3,5), $$
$$H^4(BSO_{\infty};\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}.$$

In the case of $BO$, there are more generators $\delta(w_1)$ and
 $\delta(w_1w_2)$  in degrees 2 and 4.  Thus in degrees 4 and  5 we also have  products $\delta(w_1)^2$ and  $\delta(w_1)\delta(w_2)$.

All of these lead to
$$H^1(BO_{\infty};\mathbb{Z})\cong 0,$$
$$H^i(BO_{\infty};\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}/2, \quad (i=2,3)$$
$$H^4(BO_{\infty};\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus (\mathbb{Z}/2)^2,$$
$$H^5(BO_{\infty};\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not familiar with those polynomial rings. But I wonder do you also have $\delta(w_4)$ term for the $BSO$ and $BO$ cases, and the $\delta(w_1)\delta(w_1)$ for the $BO$ case? May be there are few more $Z/2$'s.

Comment: You are right, we have $\delta (w_4)$ in $H^5(BSO)$ and $H^5(BO)$, as well as $\delta (w_1)^2$ in $H^4(BO)$. I will edit the answer

Comment: I do wonder if that $H^5$ in the first block, which originally came _before_ the $H^4$ (I re-ordered them in ascending dimension) was meant to be an $H^3$...?

Comment: @DavidRoberts thank you for the comment and edit.  Actually it was both $H^3$ and $H^5$,  I corrected.